# Помогите понять как работает программа

Tags: java

Всем привет, заранее прошу не кидаться камнями, так как пример один из самых начальных и простых, но въехать в до конца не получается. Вот кодЭЖ

```
    class Letter {
char c;
}

 public class Main {
  static void f(Letter y) {
    y.c = 'z';
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Letter x = new Letter();
        x.c = 'a';
        System.out.println("1: x.c: " + x.c);
        f(x);
        System.out.println("2: x.c: " + x.c);
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу понять логику работы f(x), поэтому решил обратиться за помощью к более опытным людям. Объясните пожалуйста как работает f(x), к чему и после чего оно обращается. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Банальное изменение значения свойства через метод, что тут может быть не понятно, не понимаю.

Comment: @And Я для кого писал, что пока не сильно в этом разбираюсь?

Comment: Так возьмите книжку и почитайте, прежде чем задавать вопрос. В любой книге об этом рассказывается, как, что, куда и почему.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Letter {
    char c;
}

public class Main {
    static void f(Letter y) {
        y.c = 'z';
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Letter x = new Letter();
        x.c = 'a';
        System.out.println("1: x.c: " + x.c);
        f(x);
        System.out.println("2: x.c: " + x.c);
    }
}
```

Разберем с самого начала:

1) В методе `main` ты создаешь объект класса `Letter` под названием `x`;

2) Переменной c объекта `x` присваивается значение 'а';

3) Печатается строка с значением переменной `c`

4) Вызывается статический метод `f(Letter y);` с аргументом `x`(объектом класса `Letter`, который мы создали в пункте 1);

5) В методе `f` переменной c объекта `x` присваевается новое значение 'z'(вместо старого 'a');

6) Опять печатается уже новое значение переменной c объекта `x`.

Думаю, смысл всего этого кода показать, что объекты в Java передаются ***по ссылке*** - вы это видите, когда вставляете свою переменную в метод, ее значение меняется внутри метода и вы печатаете уже ***новое значение***

На будущее совет: пытайтесь называть все - объекты, классы, переменные осмысленно. Ибо "x", "c" и так далее вызывают огромную путаницу не только для тех, кто читает ваш код, но и у вас в голове.